# Magento 2 getFullActionName() not working when FPC is enabled

Tags: magento2, event-observer, full-page-cache

I have an observer subscribed to controller_front_send_response_before event. in the observer i'm trying to call the page type by getFullActionName() method. But when the magento FPC is enabled, its returning empty. when i'm disabling the FPC, it is working fine as expected.
here is my code

events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_front_send_response_before">
        <observer name="vendor_module" instance="Vendor\Module\Model\Observer" shared="false" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http as HttpRequest;


class Observer implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_helper;

    public function __construct(
        \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $helper
    )
    {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $response = $observer->getEvent()->getData('response');
        $request = $observer->getEvent()->getData('request');
        $fullActionName = $request->getFullActionName();
        $response->setBody($fullActionName);
    }
}
```

Do you have any suggestion how should I achieve the desired result by keeping FPC is enabled?